# How can change the strings of a binary(Mach-O) file?

Tags: gcc, executable, mach-o

I want to change string (with new length) in binary file.
With Object File (.o) change string -> compile -> can run
but Executable File cant run

Comment: You cannot move fields in an object file without breaking it. Change the
string in the *source* file and recompile it.

Comment: i dont think so, can change the string in executable file but it very complex